# Determining dimesion of eigenspace given characteristic equation by "inspection"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A question in my textbook reads: "Find the characteristic equation of the given symmetric matrix, and then by inspection determine the dimensions of the eigenspaces."

So the question is pretty simple. I got the answers, but I gave up on trying to find the dimensions of the eigenspaces "by inspection" fairly quickly and just solved it the longhand way.

My question: Is there any solid method for determining the dimensions of the eigenspaces of a symmetric matrix when given its characteristic equation merely by inspection? If so, is it only for symmetric matrices, or can it be used for any matrix??

Comment: The characteristic equation, if factored, tells us the dimension of the generalized eigenspaces.  If the matrix is symmetric, then for each eigenvalue (characteristic root) the generalized eigenspace's dimension (algebraic multiplicity) is the same as the ordinary eigenspace's dimension (geometric multiplicity).

Comment: Even for a general matrix (not necessarily symmetric), if all the eigenvalues are distinct, then the corresponding eigenspaces have to have dimension $1$.